# Is it possible to gain access to all notifications in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I was thinking of making an app for myself only to send my iPhones notifications to my MacBook Pro and vice versa. I have a feeling that this is not possible due to privacy, however I’m going to ask anyway, is it possible just to at least get the name of the app that’s pushing the notification and the content? I have read about the ‘UNUserNotification’ and it’s not clear what permissions are allowed?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Why do you mention xcode?

Comment: As long as your phone is near your Mac (within Bluetooth range) you could write a program on your Mac that implemented ANCS to receive notifications from your phone

Comment: @Paulw11 will that be allowed by apple’s placement though?

Comment: It' s nothing to do with Apple really.  The code will be on your Mac. ANCS is an in-built part of iOS. To send notifications from your Mac to the phone would be a bit more work. You would need to investigate how to get the data from the notification centre and then convert that to a push to your phone. Again, though, the Mac is a bit more "open". You can write whatever code you like.

Comment: @Paulw11 that’s the thing, I’m guess Apple doesn’t allow you to get notification data from the Notification Centre?

Comment: Well, there's no public API, but you might be able to find the data somewhere.  You don't have the same restrictions on macOS that you do on iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Apps only have access to the notifications sent from/to that specific app, being either local notifications of push notifications. You cannot access notifications of other applications.